# UV Project modifier : is there a way to combine two UV maps in a same material?

Tags: materials, uv

I have an object that has a material (which uses textures).

I want to add a graffiti on it, so I plugged an *Add Shader* node to include my graffiti texture in the material.

Then, I use an UV Project modifier so I can "project" the graffiti where I want on that rock.

But this messes up the original textures of the object, since, I guess, the UVs are redefined by the UV Project modifier.

Is there a way to combine two UV maps in a same material ?

Comment: you don't need a modifier, you can create a second UV, then use it in an (Input) UV Map node

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a second UV map:

[image]

Then select this second UV in a *(Input) UV Map* node, and mix the 2 *Image Texture* through a *Mix Shader* for example (use the *Alpha* output of your image as factor):

[image]